# Creating a Link Text like Submit Button in Admin Page

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, design, buttons

I'm making an admin page for my plugin and I'd like to make a text link designed like the form button of admin pages.

I tried this but didn't work well.

```
<a href="" cless="button-primary" style="line-height: 2em; border-color: #298CBA; font-weight: bold; color: white; background: #21759B url(../images/button-grad.png) repeat-x scroll left top; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 -1px 0;">Submit</a>
```

I also tried just putting a submit button, expecting that the page goes to the url in the action attribute.

```
<form action="$url" target="_self">
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Does anybody know how?

Comment: The main issue is probably the misspelling of `class`, you have `cless`...

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can style a link as a button with the `button` css class:

```
<a href="#" class="button">I am a button</a>
```

You can modify a button with the primary styling by adding `button-primary`:

```
<a href="#" class="button button-primary">I am the primary button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked,

```
<?php 
$pageslug = 'the-plugin-option-page-slug';
?>
    <form method="post" action="?page=<?php echo $pageslug; ?>&tab=2">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Submit" />       
    </form>
<?php
```

I have tabbed option pages and the button just works like a link to the tab 2 page without submitting anything.